# specifying git branch for remote

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to update my webbynode pulling from github but I got the message below:

> You asked to pull from the remote 'git@github.com:sigbackup/gsapp.git', but did not specify
>   a branch. Because this is not the default configured remote for your current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line.

So I have checked out this forum for help and I found some comments regarding `.git/config` file but mine looks already fine (at least to me):

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        url = git@github.com:sigbackup/gsapp.git
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "origin"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

Am I missing something?
Any ideas how I can solve it?

PS I also tried `git pull origin git@github.com:sigbackup/gsapp.git` and I got

> fatal: Couldn't find remote ref git@github.com

Comment: what command did you run the first time?

Comment: I have a similar question at [specify-default-branch-for-a-non-default-remote-for-pull-rebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456709/specify-default-branch-for-a-non-default-remote-for-pull-rebase), but we want to do this without changing the default remote or explicitly listing the branch.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What local branch have you checked out?

What `git status` shows?

You are probably working on some other branch than the local master branch. If you want to fetch new commits from github and merge them to the local master branch, you have to:

```
git checkout master
git pull
```

If you want those commits in the branch, on which you are working, you need:

```
git pull origin master
```

You were close in your try from PS, but the last param should be branch name, not the repo url.

---

You can also just fetch new commits from github, and do not merge it into any local branch, with:

```
git fetch origin
```

Then review those changes with `git diff`, `git log`, etc, and merge later to the currently checked out branch with:

```
git merge origin/master
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.   

git checkout master 
git pull origin master 

solved my issue.

Comment: The branch names were different for me, but git merge <remote_name>/<branch_name> from within my forked repo worked. In the context of the original question <remote_name> is a remote that points to the old "working repo" directly on the local hard drive that has the changes one wants to replay.

Answer (score 6):

It's strange that you have a branch called `origin`. `origin` is used to name a *remote* automatically created during `git clone`; you will get in troubles having to disambiguate `origin`-the-branch and `origin`-the-remote. Did you add the branch manually to the `.git/config`? What commands did you run? I suspect that you messed this up.

Comment: Upvoted, but this should rightly be a comment, and not an answer to the question.